# How to get attribute from Python requests API

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using python request library to interact with API.

```
import requests

url = "https://amazon24.p.rapidapi.com/api/product"

querystring = {"keyword":"iphone","country":"US","page":"1"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "amazon24.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "key"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
print(response.text)
```

Response I am getting is something like this. I have only included first few lines of response as it is too long.

```
{"docs":[{"isBestSeller":false,"product_title":"Apple iPhone XR (64GB, (PRODUCT)RED) [Locked] + Carrier Subscription","product_main_image_url":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51YXG1bDM5L._AC_UY218_.jpg","app_sale_price":"499.00","app_sale_price_currency":"$","isPrime":true,"product_detail_url":"https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07VSWLY55","product_id":"B07VSWLY55","evaluate_rate":"4.2 out of 5 stars","original_price":null},{"isBestSeller":false,"product_title":"New Apple iPhone 12 Mini (64GB, Black) Unlocked","product_main_image_url":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71uuDYxn3XL._AC_UY218_.jpg","app_sale_price":"729.00","app_sale_price_currency":"$","isPrime":true,"product_detail_url":"https://www.amazon.com/dp/B096R76SFK","product_id":"B096R76SFK","evaluate_rate":"4.2 out of 5 stars","original_price":null}}}]}}}
```

My question is how can I extract attributes like `"product_title"` or `"app_sale_price"` from above response. Desperately need help. Thanks

Comment: [`response.json()`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) will return a dict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the response to a dictionary using [response.json()](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content).

Following that, you can access the various attributes such as `data["docs"][0]["product_title"]`

An example is as follows:

```py
data = response.json()
for doc in data["docs"]:
    print(doc["product_title"], doc["app_sale_price"])
```

You can learn more about dictionaries [here (official python docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) or [here (w3schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Your response is JSON, `requests` has handy method for such situation, just do

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
response_data = response.json()
```

then `response_data` is python object, `dict` in your case and you might do for example

```
titles = [i.get("product_title") for i in response_data["docs"]]
print(titles)
```

to get titles from `list` of `dict`s present under key `"docs"`